# Google Analytics shows events in "Realtime" Section, but does not show anything under reporting

Tags: google-analytics

While the event I am sending (with the API, not with analytics.js) is shown in the realtime section, it does not show up in the reporting area.

I was waiting a few days; pageViews that are reported the same way are well listed in reporting.

Here is a sample Request:

`https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXX-X&ds=oo&t=event&ea=testaction&ec=testcat&el=testlabel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `&cid` parameter (client ID). This is a required parameter. For a list of which parameters are required, check [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters).

Comment: I found finally that a uid (a uuid) does help too.

Comment: There is a difference between the `&cid` and `&uid` parameters. The `cid` is automatically generated by the Google Analytics library and is stored in a cookie (named `_ga`) on the user's machine. The `&uid` on the other hand should only be sent to GA when the user is "identified" (i.e. logged in). This parameter is used to achieve cross-device measurement.